# Laravel: php artisan migrate:fresh failed ``database.themes`` does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-migrations

I am trying to run php artisan migrate:fresh to publish a modification to my seeder. It partially worked, it removed all of the tables in the database but it won't recreate them because `Table 'database.themes' does not exist`. I have included my `Themes.php` model, my `ThemesController.php` and any other resources requiring `Themes` below to hopefully make sense of this.

**2020_11_14_125914_create_themes_table (Migration)**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateThemesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('themes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('theme_id');

            $table->string('theme_title')->default('Main');
            $table->string('theme_slug')->default('main')->unique();
            $table->text('theme_description')->nullable();
            $table->string('theme_uri')->default('laravel.cmsbase.com')->nullable();
            $table->string('theme_version')->default('1.0.0')->nullable();
            $table->string('theme_license')->default('The MIT License (MIT)')->nullable();
            $table->string('theme_tags')->nullable();
            $table->string('theme_type')->default('web');
            $table->string('author_name')->default('Spencer K Media');
            $table->string('author_uri')->nullable();

            $table->boolean('is_theme')->default(1)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        DB::table('themes')->insert([
            'theme_id' => '1',
            'theme_title' => 'Core theme',
            'theme_slug' => 'main',
            'theme_description' => 'Default theme for the theme package',
            'theme_uri' => 'https://laravel.cmsbase.com',
            'theme_version' => '1.0.0',
            'theme_license' => 'The MIT License (MIT)',
            'theme_tags' => 'default, simple, base',
            'theme_type' => 'web',
            'author_name' => 'Spencer K Media',
            'author_uri' => 'https://spencerkmedia.com',
            'is_theme' => 1,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('themes');
    }
}
```

**Themes.php (Model)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Themes extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    protected $fillable = ['theme_title', 'theme_slug', 'theme_uri', 'theme_version', 'theme_license', 'theme_tags', 'theme_type', 'author_name', 'author_uri', 'is_theme'];
}
```

**ThemesController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Themes;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

class ThemeSettingsController extends Controller
{
    public $themes;
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $themes = Themes::get();
        return view('admin.settings.theme', compact('themes'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function activate()
    {
        
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request, $theme, $json)
    {
        // Get the path of theme.json
        $path = glob("/resources/views/themes/{,*/}theme.json", GLOB_BRACE);

        // Parse the json file into array with $json
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);

        var_dump($json);

        $this->validate($request, [
            'is_theme' => 'accepted'
        ]);

        $theme = new Themes();

        $theme->theme_title = $json->theme_title;
        $theme->theme_slug = strtolower($json->theme_title);
        $theme->theme_description = $json->theme_description;
        $theme->theme_uri = $json->theme_uri;
        $theme->theme_version = $json->theme_version;
        $theme->theme_license = $json->theme_license;
        $theme->theme_tags = $json->theme_tags;
        $theme->theme_type = $json->theme_type;
        $theme->author_name = $json->author_name;
        $theme->author_uri = $json->author_uri;
        $theme->is_theme = $request->is_theme;
        $theme->save();
        notify()->success('Theme successfully enabled :)', 'Success');
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**RouteServiceProvider**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Models\Themes;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';

    /**
     * The controller namespace for the application.
     *
     * When present, controller route declarations will automatically be prefixed with this namespace.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    // protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $settings = Themes::get();
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () use ($settings) {
            Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes\api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes\web.php'));


            foreach ($settings as $key => $setting) {
                Route::middleware('web')
                ->group(base_path('resources/views/themes/' . $setting->theme_slug . '/route.php'));
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60);
        });
    }
}
```

**Web.php (Route File)**

```
Route::prefix('settings')->name('settings.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/home', function () {
        return view('admin.settings.index');
    })->name('index');
    Route::get('/general', function () {
        return view('admin.settings.general');
    })->name('general');
    Route::get('/site', function () {
        return view('admin.settings.site');
    })->name('site');
    Route::get('/theme', function () {
        return view('admin.settings.theme');
    })->name('theme');
});
```

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: Typically you do create (Migration) and populate (Seeder) separately. I don't remember if it's actually an exception, but either way, it's best practice to have them separated.

Comment: Did you try to remove your DB::insert statement and run the migration again ?

Comment: If i recall correctly laravel runs Providers before the command on artisan commands, so its trying to `$settings = Themes::get();` on `RouteServiceProvider` and failing, thus the error. For a temporary fix remove that code and then run the migrate command.

Comment: @MathiasHillmann please put your answer below and I will mark it, also, this service provider is required for complete functionality and im intending for this laravel package to be available for use, is there another way to make the Routing work outside of its service provider? For instance, in a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel runs Providers before the command on artisan commands, so its trying to $settings = Themes::get(); on RouteServiceProvider and failing, thus the error. For a temporary fix remove that code and then run the migrate command.

For a more permanent fix, you can check if the model/table exists before running the query:

```
    public function boot()
    {
        if($settings = Themes::get()){
            $this->configureRateLimiting();

            $this->routes(function () use ($settings) {
                Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                    ->group(base_path('routes\api.php'));

                Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                    ->group(base_path('routes\web.php'));


                foreach ($settings as $key => $setting) {
                    Route::middleware('web')
                    ->group(base_path('resources/views/themes/' . $setting->theme_slug . '/route.php'));
                }
            });
        }
    }
```